# What uses do black, grey, and brown woolen sheep have?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft you can find grey,brown,white and black sheep naturally in the wild. What uses do the grey, brown and black woolen sheep have? As far as I have concluded they aren't worth anything when dying. Do these specific colors have any special purposes? Potions or something?

Comment: They give you black, grey, and brown wool.

Comment: Each type of wool has exactly same uses. Wool color is irrelevant in crafting, as are kinds of wood - you can actually craft a bed from three different types of planks and three different colors of wool.

Comment: One of the benefits of "dying" a sheep is when using shears you can get 1 - 3 wool. Dying can only give you 1.

Comment: @Bananaman I know. I just didn't know whether or not certain colors (above) had certain meanings or usage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are useful only for getting wool of different colors. No color of wool has any special uses over another, and each can be used interchangeably for decoration and crafting. The natural sheep colors are, in increasing order of rarity:

- White (≈82%)
- Light Grey (5%)
- Dark Grey (5%)
- Black (5%)
- Brown (3%)
- Pink (0.164%)

But why only these colors? Probably because they're the colors sheep naturally come in ([mostly](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=pink%20sheep)).

You can, of course, dye sheep to get the color you want, even colors that don't spawn naturally.

Brown requires special mention, however, because it used to be *very* difficult to get cocoa beans back when they could only be found in abandoned mineshaft chests. Having brown sheep (even with a 3% spawn rate) made it much easier to get brown wool.

You can read more about [wool](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wool) and [sheep](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sheep) on the wiki.

Comment: Pink sheep also spawn naturally, with a 0.164% chance.

Comment: @RavenM It's borderline to make so many changes to a post. In future, you should consider just writing your own answer if you feel an existing answer is not up to par. It's possible these changes will be undone at some point if there's sufficient feeling that it changes the post too radically.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Agreed, but it made some not bad points, so I can work with it.

Comment: Cool, then it was a good edit and no harm done. :)

Answer (score 3):

Killing grey, brown, white, or black sheep gives you the appropriate-colored wool as an item drop.

The wool can be used for decorating, etc.

Read more in the [Sheep article on the Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sheep).